# Increasing number of mappers in sqoop command gives java heap space error

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I m using sqoop 1.4.5-cdh5.2.1 and oracle .

I m importing a small set of records of 115k from oracle .
Sqoop command works fine on setting --num-mappers to 5.
But when i set it to more than 5 , I get an error of JAVA HEAP SPACE.

Can any one tell this ,that why its happening so.

**LOG**
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.math.BigInteger.(BigInteger.java:394)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.bigTenToThe(BigDecimal.java:3380)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.bigDigitLength(BigDecimal.java:3635)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.precision(BigDecimal.java:2189)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.compareMagnitude(BigDecimal.java:2585)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.java:2566)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.BigDecimalSplitter.split(BigDecimalSplitter.java:138)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.BigDecimalSplitter.split(BigDecimalSplitter.java:69)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:721)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
2015-06-25 13:48:59 STATUS: 1
2015-06-25 13:48:59 ERROR Error (1) Sqoop failed.
2015-06-25 13:48:59 ERROR Error (1) run_sqoop

Comment: Are you using distibuter hadoop cluster / Pseudo cluster / VM box ?

Comment: please paste the err log in your question

Answer (score 0):

By default, each map and reduce task runs in its own JVM. Hence, each mapper will consume certain amount of physical memory. As you keep increasing number of mappers, memory requirement will also keep growing. If java process cannot allocate enough memory it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

In your case, system(or VM, if you are running VM) might have memory enough for max 5 mappers only.

You can run `top` command while launching >5 mappers and monitor free memory.

Comment: Actually i   have other tables also, which has million of record. For importing that data ,i used mappers more than 5.So i dont think memory will be a problem.

Comment: Was this done on same machine where you are hitting problem ?

Comment: yup..It is same machine shubhangi

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property on $HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml as below

```
<!--for Sqoop config-->
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>1024</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx512m</value>
</property>
```

Tuning for your environment, maybe plus or minus the value.
Remember modify on every nodes.

or modify virtual memory limit on yarn-site

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>4.2</value>
</property>
```

its default 2.1G